# Creating module on prestashop

Tags: module, prestashop, hook

i need to create a module on prestashop on product page , im new in prestashop idk how to do that .
This module should be on bottom of page ,it contains product technical description 
Can someone tell me how to do that 
Ps : i know nothing about prestashop Hooks .... 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: the best way is to start reading the documentation for [creating a module in prestashop](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS17/Creating+a+PrestaShop+1.7+Module)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one hook that may fit you.

`displayProductFooter`

**First you have to add the hook registration in your module install function**

```
public function install()
{
   ...
   $this->registerHook('displayProductFooter');
}
```

**Then create a function to display the content in the hook**

Save the content you want to display and use the return to send a string with all the HTML you want to print in the product footer.

In the params you will also find some useful variables like the product ID.

```
public function hookDisplayProductFooter($params)
{
    // Your content here
    return $output;
}
```

**The same procedure should work with any other hook** (as long as it's a display hook)

Comment: Thanks alot @Pol Rué